# How to access text element in selenium if it is splitted by body tags

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem while trying to access some values on the website during the process of web scraping the data. The problem is that the text I want to extract is in the class which contains several texts separated by  tags (these body tags also have texts which are also important for me).

So firstly, I tried to look for the  tag with the text I needed ('Category' in this case) and then extract the exact category from the text below this body tag assignment. I could use precise XPath but here it is not the case because other pages I need to web scrape contain a different amount of rows in this sidebar so the locations, as well as XPaths, are different.

The expected output is 'utility' - the category in the sidebar.

The website and the text I need to extract look like that (look right at the sidebar containing 'Category':

[image]

The element looks like that:

[image]

And the code I tried:

```python
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://www.statsforsharks.com/entry/MC_Squares')
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//b[contains(text(), 'Category')]/following-sibling")
for value in element:
    print(value.text)
driver.close()
```

the link to the page with the data is https://www.statsforsharks.com/entry/MC_Squares.

Thank you!

Comment: @komatiraju032 I tried all I could with XPath already :(

Comment: There are no rows as it is not the table, visually the key-value pairs of category and utility or other parameters with their values are just under each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using regex here, as the whole text comes under the 'company-sidebar-body' class, where only some text is between b tags and some are not.

So, you can the text of the class first:

```
sidebartext = driver.find_element_by_class_name("company-sidebar-body").text
```

That will give you the following:

"EOY Proj Sales: $1,000,000\r\nSales Prev Year: $200,000\r\nCategory: Utility\r\nAsking Deal\r\nEquity: 10%\r\nAmount: $300,000\r\nValue: $3,000,000\r\nEquity Deal\r\nSharks: Kevin O'Leary\r\nEquity: 25%\r\nAmount: $300,000\r\nValue: $1,200,000\r\nBite: -$1,800,000"

You can then use regex to target the category:

```
import re

c = re.search("Category:\s\w+", sidebartext).group()

print(c)
```

c will result in '**Category: Utility**' which you can then work with. This will also work if the value of the category ('Utility') is different on other pages.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I bring only 'Utility' from this text?

Comment: Also, your answer gives the output 'Category: UtilityAsking'. How to fix that?

Comment: I've tested the regex [here](https://regexr.com) using the below and I got 'Category: Utility'. I also tested the python code [here](https://w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_regex) and also got the expected result. The text from the element contains carriage returns '\r\n' so the \w+ part of the regex will just get the word it can up to a certain point - in this case the '\r\n' Maybe your text from the element doesn't include the carriage returns? Would be surprised though as your just getting the text from the element as I did.

Comment: Yes, the text does not contain /r/n symbols... So how can I bring this element with them or access the needed piece without them?

Comment: This probably isn't the best way generally, I would question if there's a better way to perform you test - such as using an API if they have one. However, in these cases you'll need to try and be imaginative. So I know that there's a h4 tag for 'Asking Deal'. So you could hold that text in a variable and use that to split the original string before performing the regex search. `header_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".company-sidebar-body>h4").text` and then 
`text_before_header = sidebartext.split(header_text, 1)[0]`. Now do the re.search on text_before_header

Answer (score 1):

There are easier ways when it's a MediaWiki website. You could, for instance, access the page data through the API with a JSON request and parse it with a much more limited DOM.

Any particular reason you want to scrape my website?